# Android Studio accept licenses

Tags: java, android, android-studio, licensing

I installed Android Studio (version 4.1.2), my java details:
[image]

I don't succeed to accept licenses.
When I try to run: "C:\Users\Damien\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses" to accept licenses, I have the following error: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema**

My SDK platforms installed is: Android 11.0 (R)
My SDK tools installed are:
[image]

What is the problem: my java version? Another SDK platform to install? Another SDK tool to install?
Any idea to accept the licenses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install java version 1.8